# NO partition on my hard-drive - can't mount

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I'm new to Linux and I am having an issue with my Hard-drive. With Windows I have never bothered with partitions on my Hard-drive. I have just put my files directly into it. I am unable to get this hard-drive to work. When I try to access the Hard-drive it comes up with the following error:

```
Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sdb1: Command-line `mount "/mnt/4018AFD318AFC66E"' exited with non-zero exit status 12: Failed to read last sector (1953515519): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdb1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

I know I could reformat the drive and create a new table or whatever but I don't want to lose everything on the hard-drive. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS: The caps lock lag bug with Ubuntu is driving me mad. :)

Comment: Don't use capslock where it's not needed.

Comment: I would love to. Unfortunately there is a bug with Ubuntu that causes this. It's not me. :) THanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to check Your filesystem using:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1
```

I'm assuming You want to check `/dev/sdb1,` if no, type there another mount point.

Comment: I'm not sure if I am being stupid or not. There is no file system as there is no partition. I used the command you gave and it displays LOTS of error messages which I can't post here because the character limit is 500.

Comment: Please use pastebin :)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Here is the error code that is presented to me:

http://pastebin.com/1eZjby7K

Comment: Please hit one more command for me, `sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: Really strange. Would you recommend just backing up my files from within a Windows install and then format/partition the disk?

http://pastebin.com/nK5pLkLu

Comment: Its always wise to have Your data backed up ;)

Comment: It would appear that one of the solutions your provided me has in fact worked. I now have access to all my files. Thanks.

Comment: so `ntfsfix` had to do the work then :) I'm glad it's working out for You!

Comment: @NickNasMoth: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**